# Mystery Shared folder in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a WebFrom application which works perfectly in a 
test (UAT ) machine but behave strangely in the Production machine.

(Code is posted to production using copy/paste file method):

So the following code:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="logoutlink" runat="server" OnClick="logoutlink_Click">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void logoutlink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();

        }
```

Works without any issues in both DEV and UAT environment but in production We get:

```
The resource cannot be found: Requested URL: /MyApp/shared/login.aspx  does not exist
```

What is surprising is this application Never Had a Shared folder. I searched the whole solution for any reference to Shared folder but could not find it .

Maybe RedirectToLoginPage Method looks for the Shared folder by default? And even if we assume this then why there is no error for identical code in DEv and UAT?

Comment: Check in the web.config.  It might say that this is the path to your login page.

Comment: Check your production web.config file. Look for the loginUrl.

Comment: ASP.Net 4.5. and interesting part is Webconfig in any machine does not have loginUrl attribute or even authentication tag.

Comment: Was it deployed in the root on the UAT box but is an Application on the production box?  I'd start by verifying that the IIS config on both machines are identical.

Comment: Error could be in IIS setup for this application. Check if you did create the virtual directory properly with rights to IIS_IUSER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `loginUrl` parameter is not set in web.config authentication tag or when you call `RedirectToLoginPage` method, by default `RedirectToLoginPage` method search for `login.aspx` page in `shared` folder by default.
You can write the link in web.config like this:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Autentificare/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>

...
```

Set the **loginUrl** link with your link.

Or you can specify the `login` URL explicit like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage("Account/Login.aspx");
```

Comment: There is no  <authentication> tag in webconfig.

Comment: @SNash you have right, if in web.config is not this tag, by default the login page is search in shared folder with login.aspx name